# how to make collection of objects which satisfy certain concept

Tags: c++, variant

I have a certain function which supposed to take as a parameter a collection of objects instantiating a certain template
currently, i implement it as
A

```
template <typename Parser, typename ParserOutput>
 bool run_parsers(const vector<Parser>& parsers, shared_ptr<vector<ParserOutput> >);
```

then 
B

```
using SemanticParsers = variant<a list of my parsers>
```

then somewhere I instantiate 
C

```
vector<SemanticParsers> pars_vect;
factory creating and loading parsers, adding them to pars_vect
run_parsers(pars_vect, ptr_parser_outputs)
```

whenever I want to add  a new parser to the list,
I made it a class which implements functionality expected by A
edit B adding new class to the B
edit registry of C which knows how to create and loaded classes

how can I do it without touching B
Basically, I want a function run_parsers to accept a collection of classes which implement a certain interface but which are not classes of the same template

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question correctly...

Pass a container of pointers/references to `Parser`, which actually point to instances of your sublcass, and use virtual methods on the `Parser` base class to operate on all of them. You won't need the variant. However, each class might need a bit of static code to add itself into your factory (otherwise it will need to know about all the parsers).

And - note at run-time, there is no such thing as a collection of classes, so you have your vocabulary a bit mixed up.

Comment: right, sorry . was fast typing,    I'd prefer to use static binding rather than dynamic in this case.

Comment: @Andrei Lopatenko maybe then you should make this function into a template functor  class and that list would be formed inside along with actual run_parser method. Static solution have own limitations, because real compilers have technical limits on how many parameters or how complex templates they can handle.

Comment: @AndreiLopatenko: You can't really have it both ways. If you want the general code not to be aware of which parsers you have, it can't all be bound at compile-time. But anyway - can you explain your preference?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why have a problem, if you want avoid registering a list of classes, you probably have to use polymorphism, a BaseParser class which provides interface and allows type erasure.
For rest it's what templates are designed to solve.

Your collection likely should be a template parameter of template.

```
template <template<class> typename Col, typename BaseParser, typename Out>
bool run_parsers(const Col<BaseParser>& parsers, shared_ptr<Col<ParserOutput> >);
```